# Polearm master vs disengage

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, opportunity-attack

So I know that specific beats generic, but I'm not fully sure about polearm master. Anyone know for sure how these should interact? Have there been official rulings?

1. If I start a disengage action, and move into/through reach of 1 or more polearm equipped polearm masters, does polearm mastery give them the opportunity attack or not?
   On PHB page 168, Polearm master says:

   > When wielding a glaive, halberd, pike, or quarterstaff, other creatures
   >   provoke an opportunity attack from you when they enter the reach you
   >   have with that weapon.

vs disengage:

> If you take the disengage action, your movement doesn't provoke
>   opportunity attacks for the rest of the turn.

So, is the feat more specific than disengage? I'm on the fence with this one.

2. Normally, someone who doesn't move/act/react also doesn't trigger opportunity attack, but what about the case of polearm master feat?

Opportunity attacks on PHB: 195 says:

> You also don't provoke an opportunity attack when you teleport or when
>   someone or something moves you without using your movement, action, or
>   reaction.

Is this such a "basic" rule, that it prevents polearm master from gaining an opportunity attack, even though the feat is more specific? I'm apt to give the win to no opportunity attack here, but I'm interested in what you think.

Comment: I think your second question is different enough that you should really split it into a separate post (you can [edit] your post at any time.) As it stands right now, someone could take a position on only one of them, or two different positions, one of which someone might not agree with, which makes voting tough - and it's in everyone's best interest to have the best answers rise to the top.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

### There is no Opportunity Attack

The Polearm Master Feat is clear that the reactionary attack is an Opportunity Attack, and Disengage says that your movement doesn't cause Opportunity Attacks.

In your example, moving into a Polearm Master's reach while Disengaging doesn't trigger the Feat's Opportunity Attack. Think of it as sort of batting away the guy's glaive before moving in.

Disengage should work this way, otherwise a Polearm Master can *always* attempt to Opportunity Attack against an approaching foe.

Answer (score 0):

'Disengage' is there for a character to get out of the range / flee / move away from enemies.

If disengaging one character might accidentally, or due to lack of options move towards another enemy with a polearm (+Polearm Master), in this case yes, the Polearm Master doesn't grant the opportunity attack.