# Does an enemy that takes Disengage action provoke opportunity attack when moving toward someone with a pike and Polearm Mastery and Sentinel feat?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, opportunity-attack

[Polearm master vs disengage](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/96735/polearm-master-vs-disengage)

I have a pike, Polearm Master, and Sentinel feats. An enemy that already takes Disengage action moves toward me.

The Polearm Master feat gives me an opportunity attack when they enter my range, however, the Sentinel feat negates Disengage.

**Does this mean that the enemy will provoke opportunity attack when they enter my reach?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Strict RAW, No.

Sentinel negates Disengage when it is used before *leaving* your reach:

> Creatures provoke opportunity attacks from you even if they take the Disengage action before leaving your reach.

However this enemy has taken the Disengage action before *entering* your reach - as such this benefit of Sentinel will not apply.

## In my personal opinion, RAI, Yes.

In the general case, opportunity attacks only happen when you leave an enemy's reach. The very naming of Disengage underlies the lack of consideration for opportunity attacks in other situations. In my opinion, one of the intended benefits of Sentinel is to negate Disengage actions, and the "leaving your reach" rider is only there as a clarification (since that's when opportunity attacks generally occur), and was not intended as a restriction.

Polearm Master's opportunity attacks are a special case not considered by any of this wording, and in my opinion should still be able to benefit from this effect of Sentinel.

Comment: I would argue that a character starting their turn outside of your reach and then entering your reach is still "before leaving your reach". It does not say "before being out of reach".